# Changing maildir in mutt takes ages "Reading" the new maildir

Tags: mutt, maildir

It takes many seconds in [`mutt`](http://ports.su/mail/mutt) to `c`hange to a different maildir.

The following message appears as the new maildir is being read:

```
Reading /…/Maildir/.…... 1780/6926 (25%)
```

This takes ages! And is a total waste of IO, as only the bottom of the mailbox is ever examined, so, there is absolutely no need to look at each message, which, frankly, defeats the whole purpose of the maildir format, where it's actually very cheap to skip messages compared to mbox, and very expensive to load all of them.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the compile-time configuration of `mutt`, you may have the `hcache` ("header cache") feature enabled.  With this feature enabled, `mutt` will be able cache the headers of the messages in Maildir (and IMAP) folders, greatly decreasing the time it takes to open such a folder.

To use the `hcache` feature, add a line in your `.muttrc` file:

```
set header_cache = "/path/to/cache_folder"
```

Further reading: https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/Caching